# how to include rate this App button in a application

Tags: iphone, button, rate

I have this code in a button click for ratting this app

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnratethisApp:(id)sender
{

    NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str]; 
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];

    // Here is the app id from itunesconnect
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@289382458", str]; 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```

but nothing happens when I click the button,my need is I want to set a alert view to show like the ordinary alert like ratethisapp,nothanks,later.If I tap the ratethisapp I will redirected to the ring page of appstore.How to active this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator or on the device?

Comment: @Till sir i am testing it in stimulator

Comment: well then the below answer by Nick Lockwood applies - you should up vote and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The itms-apps: URL syntax doesn't work on the simulator but works fine on the device, so that's probably the only thing wrong with your code and if you try it on a device it will work fine.

Unrelated tip: You can concatenate strings using the stringByAppendingString: and stringByAppendingFormat: methods, that will save some code versus the way you are building your string currently.